# Sou iniciante e fiz uma calculadora em JavaScript que deveria quando aperto o botão somar mas não funciona o botão

Tags: javascript

```js
function somar(){
    var tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1')
    var tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2')
    var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
    var n1 = Number(tn1.value)
    var n2 = Number(tn2.value)
    var s = n1 + n2
    res.innerHTML = 's'
    window.alert ('O resultado da soma é, ' + s + '!')
}
```

```html
<h1>Somando Valores</h1>
<input type="number" name=""txtn1" id=""txtn1" >+
<input type="number" name=""txtn2" id=""txtn2" >
<input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
<div id="res">  Resultado</div>
```

Comment: Cara, desculpa, não consigo entender a pergunta. Tenta editar, dando mais detalhes e formatando o código, a fim de que alguém possa reproduzir o problema, entender o que está acontecendo e então, te ajudar.

Comment: Erro de digitação, tanto o `name` quanto o `id` dos inputs tem uma aspas a mais. Por exemplo, em vez de `id=""txtn1"` deveria ser `id="txtn1"` (repare que no seu código tem duas aspas logo depois do `=`)

Answer (score 0):

Cara, a lógica está correta, foi só um erro de digitação. Voce colocou duas aspas duplas após o name e o id. Segue abaixo o ajuste.

```js
function somar(){
    var tn1 = window.document.getElementById('txtn1')
    var tn2 = window.document.getElementById('txtn2')
    var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
    var n1 = Number(tn1.value)
    var n2 = Number(tn2.value)
    var s = n1 + n2
    res.innerHTML = 's'
    window.alert ('O resultado da soma é, ' + s + '!')
}
```

```html
<h1>Somando Valores</h1>
<input type="number" name="txtn1" id="txtn1" >+
<input type="number" name="txtn2" id="txtn2" >
<input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
<div id="res">  Resultado</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).